# How to prevent a single program from killing my desktop's performance?

Tags: performance, desktop

I have to use [Zoom](https://zoom.us/) for videoconferencing (the Linux client looks like an Electron based app).

Whenever I'm on a video call, the overall performance of my desktop degrades significantly. Interacting with the desktop environment, switching tabs, using webpages, typing a Google Doc... all feels extremely slow and unresponsive.

I'm sure that the poor client implementation is to blame here, but unfortunately, there is nothing I can do about it. What I find interesting is that the system resources do not seem to be fully exhausted. Processor (Core i7-8665U) operates at around 50-80% usage and there is plenty of free RAM. So intuitively, there should be enough performance available for other tasks. But it isn't.

Why could this be happening? For example, even if I artificially make the CPU operate at 100% (via several infinite for-cycles), the desktop environment remains responsive.

Can I do anything about it? Can I limit Zoom somehow so that all other processes can grab whatever resources they need to run smoothly? I tried to play with `nice` or `cpulimit` but the only thing I have achieved was a choppy video call without improving the responsiveness of my system.

For the record, I'm running Kubuntu 19.10 with Plasma 5.16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular case involving videoconferencing, the answer turned out to be surprising: **the input latency and non-responsiveness is caused by the desktop effects!**

If I turn off the desktop effects (KDE / Kwin has a default shortcut for it, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>), the desktop experience becomes immediately smooth again.

Answer (score 0):

You might start that program on the command line (so in a terminal, using your interactive shell) using a combination of [nice(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nice.1.html) and [ionice(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ionice.1.html).

You could also wrap that Zoom program invocation in a shell script or C program doing some [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) (e.g. `RLIMIT_RTTIME`, `RLIMIT_NPROC`, `RLIMIT_NICE`, `RLIMIT_AS` etc...)

However, video teleconferencing is very resource hungry. No software solution can overcome that need of computing resources. You may want to lower video resolution and bandwidth.

> So intuitively, there should be enough performance available for other tasks.

Maybe your Zoom is single-threaded ! (see [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) for more), in such case a [multi-core processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) does not help.

Consider perhaps using [Jitsi Meet](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet) thru a recent Firefox or Chrome browser. It is used in France on [FramaTalk](https://framatalk.org/accueil/en/) (a non-profit association whose servers are, in March 2020, overheating with Covid19) and enables you to lower video resolution or bandwidth.

Comment: Will try nice and ionice!

Zoom is the company's choice so I can't do anything about it :) And please note that Zoom on its own is performing just fine, it's the rest of the system that annoys me. If Zoom was single-threaded, then I'd assume that the rest of the system can utilize my three remaining physical cores and work as smooth as usual.