# Is it possible to maintain performance of "preferred" applications when certain resources are limited?

Tags: performance, virtual-memory

I work as a web developer, and due to the tools I generally have running (not to mention web browsers) I generally have high RAM usage at all times. Most of the time, my system handles this just fine. Occasionally, I will open a process and suddenly RAM will spike, and the computer will become totally unusable - I can't click any windows, even to close or kill the processes that are consuming resources. Usually this lasts for a minute or longer, sometimes I'm forced to reboot, and it tends to strike when I can't just wait for the system to recover itself.

I am wondering how I can better protect myself against this circumstance. A common example is where I need to demonstrate something - I have a bunch of processes in the background consuming resources, and I'm in a video call. It's fine if the processes choke up or even die, but it's very bad for me if the call is interrupted - since I can't even explain what is happening to my team.

This makes me wonder whether it's possible to reserve RAM for "special" processes - so I can say that my video call must have at least 1GB (to pick a number at random) and other processes will fight for the remaining available. By itself I am not actually sure this will work, but maybe those "not special" processes would just be killed if the RAM usage is too high.

I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/575351/how-to-prevent-a-single-program-from-killing-my-desktops-performance) which sounds like the same problem, but the answer seems to be "it fixed itself". I'm not sure whether I can use `nice` in this case.

Comment: "thrashing": do you mean page table cache trashing? Or just L2 / L3 cache thrashing? But what you describe sounds like absolutely neither. If anything, your system might need to *swap* memory to permanent storage. Or, your in your videocall example, the situation seems much more that you're simply CPU-bounded, and maybe thermal throttling might even be intensifying that situation. (and if anything, the solution is to limit the video calling software's CPU hunger, not to enable it; video encoders can use virtually all the CPU available to optimize video quality.)

Comment: but yeah, the problem here is that your question seems to start from an incorrect assumption.

Comment: @MarcusMüller My understanding of thrashing is not very nuanced - I did not mean to imply that I knew this was the direct cause of poor performance. I've removed it from the question, as I probably won't be able to answer any clarifying questions. I am quite sure that RAM is the issue and not CPU, since the issue only presents itself when my RAM usage is particularly high beforehand.

Comment: I think you can try using `nice`or `renice` to give different processes different priority (low nice value <--> high priority and high nice value <--> low priority)?

Comment: If it is not enough to swap them out, you can kill the processes with the highest nice values (positive nice values).